# What is 国之大者 as appears from time to time in the words of Chinese leader?

Tags: word

This seems to be a buzz word of the top leader of China and it does sound important. But what does it really mean?

Answer (score 5):

大 has the meaning of 'utmost important'

国之大者 means 'the most important thing to a nation' -- the most important thing to a nation is a correct national policy and governance system (not its power)

Similarly: 俠之大者 means 'the most important quality of a swordsman' -- the most important thing to a chivalrous swordsman is his principle and conviction to justice and morality (not his skill)

Answer (score 2):

Per Baidu.com:

“国之大者”原文为“国者、天下之大器也，重任也，不可不善为择所而后错之，错险则危”。 以上这段话出自《荀子·王霸》，用白话文解释就是，治国是极为重大的事，一定要认真选择立国之道和治国之人担当这样的重任，一旦在这方面问题上出错，国家就危险了。 可以理解为，**一个国家选择正确的国策和由杰出的人才掌管这个国家，便是“国之大者”。**

[国之大者 出处](https://www.bing.com/search?q=%E5%9B%BD%E4%B9%8B%E5%A4%A7%E8%80%85%20%E5%87%BA%E5%A4%84&cvid=54a037d880984dfcb3efa58f2a5541aa&aqs=edge.3.69i57j0l7j69i60.7297j0j4&FORM=ANAB01&PC=U531)

Comment: Thanks. Some Chinese-language media might have misused this phrase or made it interchangeable with 国之重器.

Answer (score 0):

A direct translation of “国之大者” is "what is the really big thing of a nation".